# Is there a way to save paypal account like a card in React native?

Tags: react-native

I want to save paypal account to my React Native app just like we save card details. Is there a way?

I have tried available paypal libraries but they doesn't offer this functionality. I want to retrieve payment details from paypal and save it in DB and use it while doing payments